# Android Studio cant run a single class

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-intent, bufferedreader

I have a problem with Android Studio.
I have two classes with almost the same code.

The first class is running without a problem but the second class  causes an error.

The first class:

```
package com.example.guenes2.emobilitylab;

import android.content.ComponentName;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;

public class NEFZ2array extends AppCompatActivity implements Serializable {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    FileReader file = null;
    try {
        file = new FileReader("NEFZ.txt");
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
    ArrayList<Double> Nlist = new ArrayList<Double>();
    int i=0;
    Double d= null;
    try {
        BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(file);
        String s=null;
        while((s=input.readLine())!=null) {
            StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(s,",");
            while(st.hasMoreTokens()) {
                try {
                    d = Double.parseDouble(st.nextToken());
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                Nlist.add(i, d);
            }
        }
        input.close();
    } catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    for(double j:Nlist) {
        System.out.println(j);
    }
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_nefz2array);

}
}
```

The second class:

```
package com.example.guenes2.emobilitylab;

import android.content.ComponentName;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

import android.content.Intent;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;

public class WLTP2array extends AppCompatActivity implements Serializable {

public void main(String[] args) {
    FileReader file = null;
    try {
        file = new FileReader("WLTP.txt");
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
    ArrayList<Double> Wlist = new ArrayList<Double>();
    int i=0;
    Double d= null;
    try {
        BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(file);
        String s=null;
        while((s=input.readLine())!=null) {
            StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(s,",");
            while(st.hasMoreTokens()) {
                try {
                    d = Double.parseDouble(st.nextToken());
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                Wlist.add(i, d);
            }
        }
        input.close();
    } catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    for(double k:Wlist) {
        System.out.println(k);
    }
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_wltp2array);
}
}
```

The Error of the second class:

```
Error running 'WLTP2array': The activity must be exported or contain an intent-filter
```

I dont understand what is the reason for this error. I know I can fix the error with changing the Manifest but then I cant run this single class. The whole app runs.

Thanks for your advice.

Here is my Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.guenes2.emobilitylab">

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".fahrzeugsimulation" />
    <activity android:name=".elektrofahrzeug" />
    <activity android:name=".hybridfahrzeug" />
    <activity android:name=".brennstoffzellenfahrzeug" />
    <activity android:name=".ergebnisse" />
    <activity android:name=".ausfuehrlicher" />
    <activity android:name=".VerlRadleistung" />
    <activity android:name=".HaufRad" />
    <activity android:name=".VerlEM" />
    <activity android:name=".BetriebsVKM" />
    <activity android:name=".bearbeitung" />
    <activity android:name=".info" />
    <activity android:name=".info2" />
    <activity android:name=".info3" />
    <activity android:name=".ergebnisse2" />
    <activity android:name=".elektroTabelle" />
    <activity android:name=".hybridTabelle" />
    <activity android:name=".brennstoffzelleTabelle" />
    <activity android:name=".WLTP2array" />
    <activity android:name=".NEFZ2array" />
</application>

</manifest>
```

EDIT-------------------------------------------------------------------

I tried to fix it with the help but now the first class is showing the same error and the second one is running correct. Maybe the two classes affect each other.

Comment: Do you have the intent filter in your Manifest?

Comment: Yes I added my manifest. You can see it there.

Comment: I have seen both of your questions. You seem to be confused about Android development. There is no `main()` method in Android. You don't "run classes" in Android. In Android, there are components that are started by the Android framework. Those components are: `Activity, Service, BroadcastReceiver and Provider`. You can't start any of these components yourself, they can only be instantiated and started by the Android framework. This is the reason why you are having all these problems.

Answer (score 1):

**Firstly**, as the error indicated

> Error running 'WLTP2array': The activity must be exported or contain an intent-filter

You need to register your activity inside the `manifest.xml` file something similar as your activity `NEFZ2array`. Check your `manifest.xml` and declare `WLTP2array` properly.

**Secondly**, change below line

```
public void main(String[] args)
```

to

```
public static void main(String[] args)
```

You need key word **static** for **main** method, to run that class.

**------ Edit ------**

**Finally**, edit your **Run/Debug Configuration**.

**Add New Configuration** -> **Application**, Select **Main class**, Configure **Working directory** and **Use classpath of module**

[image]

Then right click on the class to run your single class, see below:

[image]

So, in the end, when you open your "**Run/Debug Configurations**", it should be something like below:

[image]

Comment: Thanks I didnt see that. I changed that but the error is the same.

Comment: For Android, adding a "main" method is not recommended. If you just want to test your functionalities, then you should put it as an test case, either unit test case or android insturmentation test case.

Answer (score 0):

You must have this in your Manifest:

```
<activity android:name=".WLTP2array" >
    <intent-filter>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Comment: But I want to run the class not the app.